# Web Crawling. Not able to crawl the data correctly

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, web-crawler, nokogiri, open-uri

```rb
require 'open-uri'   
require 'nokogiri'    

url = "https://grofers.com/cn/grocery-staples/cid/16" 
response = open(url).read
parsed_data = Nokogiri::HTML(response)

results = []

content = parsed_data.css('.section-right').css('.products products--grid').each do |row|
  title = row.css('a.product__wrapper').text
  puts title

  results << content
end
```

Comment: Right, and what has gone wrong

Comment: There is no output.